# SQL script to make another SQL script

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-scripts

I would need a SQL script that reads the data in the table based on an ID and then generates another SQL script. The generated script should be able to update and insert data previously selected by ID.

I know the update and insert commands, but I don’t know exactly how to create a script that builds a script from existing data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to accomplish here.

Here I use a query to find what id I going to update.
update table set updated=now() where id in (select id from table where updated is null);

Here I create a query that I run (command differs depending on sql engine, you have to google yours)
SET SQL = select 'select * from table where id = ' + select max(id) from table where updated is null; -- Will generate something like 'select * from table where id = 2'
SELECT SQL; -- Print the query that will rune
exec(SQL); -- Run the query you generated